# Extjs 6.0 - Building app without cmd

Tags: javascript, extjs

now i am trying to learn about sencha extjs new version. Does anyone know any tutorial of how to make a project without sencha cmd?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Asking for links is off topic, SO requires you to show the code you've tried.

Comment: What is the problem to use Sencha CMD? It is very easy to set up an app with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@sonseiya First all.. Sencha CMD it is most usefull tool for sencha apps, not only will generate you app, your MVC structure,models,stores but also will compile for IOS, Android, WINDOWS, focus on use "[Universal App](https://www.sencha.com/blog/using-sencha-ext-js-6-to-build-universal-apps/)" way, sencha CMD will put all your code in one single file and will be ofuscated, cool ha!

Now.. to answer your question, yes it is posible, sencha cmd uses the microloader an script to do smart stuf based on you browser.. but for your case, you need to use old way: ext.onready and create script tags on your html header.. for example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ext JS </title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/ext-all.css" /> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="path/ext-all.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    Ext.onReady(function() {
        Ext.Msg.alert('Alert');     
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Note: you must to use explicity requires because there are not microloader that is in charge of read all dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

yes I know how some good tutorial : [Ext JS 5](http://miamicoder.com/ext-js-tutorials/)
Sencha Cmd is really awesome and powerfull tool, but creating an application from scratch is really good for learning. Basically this tutorial works good enough for Ext JS 6 as well. 
I hope it helps

Comment: Link is dead (guess that shows why it is good practice to post answers, not links)